# Mac OS X Terminal startup without a window

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm curious if anyone has found a good way to have the Terminal app on a Mac open without opening a window. The startup preference has the options "New window with settings:" or open a specific window group, but I would prefer it just open nothing to begin with. I've tried saving a window group with no windows in it, but it reverts to just opening a default window again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any option to prevent a window from opening when Terminal is started, but you could check whether the current `bash` session was started at *exactly* the same time Terminal was started. If that's the case, the `bash` session should exit.

You will see a window appearing and disappearing for a fraction of a second, though.

Add the following code (tested on Mac OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard) [*see my note below*] and OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion)) to the beginning of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
shell_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $$ | grep -v STARTED)
terminal_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $(ps -A -o pid -o command | grep '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn' | grep -v grep | cut -d '/' -f 1) | grep -v STARTED)
if [ "X$shell_started" == "X$terminal_started" ]; then exit; fi
```

Code explanation:

> `shell_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $$ | grep -v STARTED`) : execute `ps`
>   to print when process identifed by variable `$$` started (`$$`
>   [expands to the PID ot this `bash` session](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)). Then filter out the
>   header (which contains the word `STARTED`). Assign resulting value to
>   variable `shell_started`.
>
> `ps -A -o pid -o command | grep
>   '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn' |
>   grep -v grep | cut -d '/' -f 1` : execute `ps` to print all process
>   command names, select the one that matches the full path to Terminal,
>   filter out any spurious `grep` processes and extract process ID with
>   `cut`.
>
> `terminal_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $(...) | grep -v STARTED)` :
>   execute `ps` to print when process Terminal started, and filter out
>   the header (which contains the word `STARTED`).
>
> (I had to create `terminal_started` in two steps to get rid of TABs
>   `ps` added to the output.)
>
> `if [ "X$shell_started" == "X$terminal_started" ]; then exit; fi` :
>   Compare both dates and if equal, exit the shell, that is, close the
>   Terminal window.

If it is not working for you (as it was the case for the OP, who uses Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)), try:

```
shell_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $$ | grep -v STARTED)
terminal_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $(ps -A -o pid -o command | grep '/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn' | grep -v grep | tail -n 1| cut -d '/' -f 1) | grep -v STARTED)
if [ "X$shell_started" == "X$terminal_started" ]; then exit; fi
```

(The only difference here is a `tail` in `terminal_started` which selects the last entry printed by `ps`, in case there's more than one.)

---

*Note for Mac OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard)*:
On my old PowerBook G4 I noticed that sometimes there was a one sec difference between the starting times of Terminal and the current `bash` session. If you are running into similar problems with a slow computer, add these three lines lines to the end of the code above:

```
one_second_before=$(expr "$shell_started" : '.*:\([0-9][0-9]\) .*' - 1)
shell_started_one_second_before=$(echo $shell_started | sed 's/\(.*:\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\( .*\)/\1'$one_second_before'\3/')
if [ "X$shell_started_one_second_before" == "X$terminal_started" ]; then exit; fi
```

There's a boundary condition this code doesn't handle well, namely, when the shell was started in second 0, but I didn't want to add further complexity.

Comment: Interesting, I like the idea, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.
shell_started is Tue Jan 29 02:52:04 2013
but
terminal_started is Tue Jan 29 02:52:04 2013 Tue Jan 29 02:52:04 2013 Tue Jan 29 02:52:04 2013 Tue Jan 29 02:52:04 2013
etc... It seems there are too many entries being found by terminal_started?

Comment: I tested it with Mountain Lion (10.8), which OS X version is your Mac running? Could you add this to your `~/.bash_profile`, close Terminal, open it and paste the output? `terminal_pid=$(ps -A -o pid -o command | grep Terminal | grep -v grep | cut -d '/' -f 1); echo "Terminal PID is $terminal_pid"; echo "Terminal started at $(ps -A -o lstart $terminal_pid | grep -v STARTED)"; echo "Terminal PID with BSD syntax is $(ps aux | grep Terminal | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')"`

Comment: Output: Terminal PID is   551 
29726 
Terminal started at Sun Jan 27 16:19:22 2013    
Sun Jan 27 16:19:27 2013    
Sun Jan 27 16:19:27 2013    
... etc Many more of these. Thu Jan 31 22:45:20 2013    
Thu Jan 31 22:45:20 2013    
Terminal PID with BSD syntax is 29726
551. Also, I am running 10.6.8

Comment: Thanks, could you 1) Post output of command `ps -A -o pid -o command | grep Terminal` and 2) Try the code in the answer modifying `terminal_started` to `terminal_started=$(ps -A -o lstart $(ps -A -o pid -o command | grep Terminal | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | cut -d '/' -f 1) | grep -v STARTED)` (notice the `head -n 1`) and report back?

Comment: Cool, I read up a little on this and was able to use tail instead of head in your modified terminal_started line to grab the last entry. This seems to have worked just as you said. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I've edited the answer to include your feedback on using `tail`.